# Is there any way to get a specific view in the listView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I'm just trying to make a basic app with a simple listView and if we click items of this view it will vanish and after all the items in the view are in a invisible position, we should get all back to visible.

I've already written a code to vanish the items when clicked but got stuck at reversing those back to visible cuz **I didn't find a way to get a specific item in a listView** to set every view visible by using a loop ---

My Activity Main XML file --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Main activity java file ---

```
package com.example.listviewdemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView myListView = findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        ArrayList<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();

        members.add("Iron Man");
        members.add("Captain America");
        members.add("Thor");
        members.add("Hulk");
        members.add("Captain Marvel");

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, members);

        myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        final int[] actionPosition = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4};

        final int[] actualPosition = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                int visibility = view.getVisibility();
                int viewItem = adapterView.getPositionForView(view);

                Log.i("Visibility", ""+ visibility +" of item "+ viewItem);

                actualPosition[viewItem] = visibility;

                Log.i("actualPositionArray", Arrays.toString(actualPosition));




                if (Arrays.equals(actionPosition, actualPosition)) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "matched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    for (int index = 0; index<actionPosition.length; index++){

                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        View counter = (View) myListView.getChildAt(index);

                        counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                    // reverting actualPosition array!--

                    for (int ind = 0; ind<actualPosition.length; ind++) {

                        actualPosition[ind] = 0;

                    }

                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

In a nutshell, I'm trying to get a specific view in the listView to make it visible, that's all I need!

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is the solution you are looking for.

What you need is the [getChildAt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#getChildAt(int)) method.

So, try tho change the `if` statement in the click listener with the code snippet below.

```
if (Arrays.equals(actionPosition, actualPosition)) {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "matched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int index = 0; index<actionPosition.length; index++){
         // use the getChildAt(index) to get the views in a ListView
         View counter = (View) myListView.getChildAt(index);
         counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Also if you want the action to be repeated consider to reset the `actualPosition` array.

**Edit**

In the comments section you asked to modify the animation so every view appear back with a delay of 1 second. Change the `for` loop with the following one and add the `helperFunction` in your Activity class.

```
 for (int index = 0; index<actionPosition.length; index++){
                        helperFunction(index);
                    }
```

```
private void helperFunction(final int index){
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                View counter = (View) myListView.getChildAt(index);
                counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, (index * 1000) + 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already commented the loop I've used for resetting the ```actualPosition``` array in the code!

Comment: Hey, I've updated my code and I've added a time sleep of 1 seconds in the loop where I'm making the view(s) visible so that it get a smooth transition of 1 second waiting in between, but **it's behaving like all the view(s) are coming back to visible position after 5 seconds (sum of time sleep) at the same time**, **I want it to come back visible in a proper manner like waiting for 1 seconds before making the next view visible**, Please help!